# Spatial operations with curvilinear data in program stars for R

Tags: r, r-sf, r-raster, r-stars

I'm new to the package `stars` for `R` and am trying to do basic spatial operations with curvilinear data. I am using netCDF climate data. I am able to read the netcdf into r along with a shapefile I would like to use to specify the area in which I want to conduct analyses. I have tried to crop the file directly using `st_crop()` but receive the following error:

```
Warning message:
In st_crop.stars(test, wrst) : crop only crops regular grids
```

I then tried to warp the stars object using code like this:

```
warp <- test %>% st_set_crs(3338) %>% st_warp(st_as_stars(st_bbox(), dx = 2))
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in colrow_from_xy(pts, x, NA_outside = TRUE) : 
  colrow_from_xy not supported for curvilinear objects
```

Do I need to 'flatten' my curvilinear grid in order to conduct analyses in a given region? If so, how do I do that? Or, conversely, if I am able to conduct operations like `st_crop()` or the equivalent of `raster` operations `calc()` or `stackApply()` using a curvilinear grid, can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks so much.

Comment: You most likely need to regrid the netcdf file to a latlon grid covering the required domain. An option in R is rcdo, which I was once developing: https://github.com/r4ecology/rcdo.

Comment: @RobertWilson thank you - I will look into this. However, your GitHub page says the package will not work on Windows platforms, which is what I use. Has that changed with the newer versions of CDO or your package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured it out and it was quite simple. I was able to subset the stars object using the shapefile with this simple code: `test[wrst]`. No warping or resampling necessary.